# Query Hive view with Redshift Spectrum

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to query a Hive view with Redshift Spectrum but it gives me this error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   loc->length() > 5 && loc->substr(0, 5) == "s3://" - 
  query:     12103470
  location:  scan_range_manager.cpp:272
  process:   padbmaster [pid=1769]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

Is is possible to query Hive views from Redshift Spectrum? I'm using Hive Metastore (not Glue Data Catalog).

I wanted to have a view to restrict access to the original table, with a limited set of columns and partitions. And also because my original table (Parquet data) has some Map fields so I wanted to do something like that to make it easier to query from Redshift as Map fields are a bit complicated to deal with in Redshift:

```
CREATE view my_view AS
SELECT event_time, event_properties['user-id'] as user_id, event_properties['product-id'] as product_id, year, month, day
FROM my_events
WHERE event_type = 'my-event'  -- partition
```

I can query the table my_events from Spectrum but it's a mess because properties is a Map field, not a Struct so I need to kind of explode it into several rows in Redshift.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems Spectrum always looks for a S3 path when external tables and views are queried.
This is valid for external tables because those will always have a location but views will never have an explicit S3 location.

```
Error type    -> Assert
Error context -> context: loc->length() > 5 && loc->substr(0, 5) == "s3://"
```

In case of a hive view,
`loc->length()` will return 0, and the whole statement will return `False` and result in assertion error.

Confirmation for this could be the second clause:

```
loc->substr(0, 5) == "s3://"
```

It is expecting the location to be a S3 path and if we count number of chars in `"s3://"` it is `5`, which also confirms the first clause :

```
loc->length() > 5
```

Looks like Spectrum does not support Hive Views (or in general any object without an explicit S3 path)

Comment: Ok thank you!  I thought more about it and it makes sense for Spectrum not to support Hive views in general because for example my view was created with Spark and could be using some Spark specific functions that don't exist in Redshift Spectrum.